# Maven deploy enunciate plugin output to a different project

Tags: maven, enunciate

I am currently working with "enunciate" plugin to generate the API documentation for out website.

I would like to separate the documentation from the API into different projects that will be deployed together to the same tomcat server as a part of continues delivery.

So what I need now is to modify the the maven configuration that will "know" the other project and will deploy the output to it.

Here is the enunciate maven plugin configuration that I have now:

> ```
>            <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>1.26.2</version>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <phase>prepare-package</phase>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>docs</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                     <configuration>
>                         <docsDir>${project.build.directory}/docs</docsDir>
>                         <docsDir>${project.build.directory}/${warName}/docs</docsDir>
>                         <configFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/enunciate.xml</configFile>
>                     </configuration>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>         </plugin>
> ```

So now I don't really understand how to reference a different project in the `<docsDir>`

Answer (score 1):

Enunciate doesn't have the capability to "merge" documentation artifacts from different projects. What you're going to have to do is create a separate "uber-project" that has dependencies on all the projects you want to merge and have that project generate the documentation for you per [Multi-Module Projects](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/Multi-Module-Projects).